# Change program from getting music from iTunes to local file using URL

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, stream, multipeer-connectivity

I am currently trying to make an app stream raw data from mic over mulipeer connectivity. 
I have been using this tutorial as a base https://robots.thoughtbot.com/streaming-audio-to-multiple-listeners-via-ios-multipeer-connectivity
Now however I am struggling with changing the URL from itunes library to my local file. 
I am no advanced programmer and this is some kind of summer project. 
When the program is getting music from itunes library it uses this code:

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
if (self.outputStreamer) return;
self.song = mediaItemCollection.items[0];

NSMutableDictionary *info = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
info[@"title"] = [self.song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] ? [self.song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle] : @"";
info[@"artist"] = [self.song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] ? [self.song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist] : @"";

MPMediaItemArtwork *artwork = [self.song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork];
UIImage *image = [artwork imageWithSize:self.albumImage.frame.size];
if (image)
    info[@"artwork"] = image;

if (info[@"artwork"])
    self.albumImage.image = info[@"artwork"];
else
    self.albumImage.image = nil;

self.songTitle.text = info[@"title"];
self.songArtist.text = info[@"artist"];
[self.session sendData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[info copy]]];

NSArray *peers = [self.session connectedPeers];

if (peers.count) {
    self.outputStreamer = [[TDAudioOutputStreamer alloc] initWithOutputStream:[self.session outputStreamForPeer:peers[0]]];

    [self.outputStreamer streamAudioFromURL:[self.song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];
    [self.outputStreamer start];
```

But I want it to get music from the recorder:

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"MyAudioMemo.m4a",
                           nil];
NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
```

I have been struggling with this for a while now and would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: You should pass an error pointer to those various AVAudio* method calls youa re doing.  Once you do that, I'd want to know: do you get a specific error somewhere in the code?  if so, what is it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i dont know how to to this. i tried this:  var error: NSError?
var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

if error != nil {
    println("Error executing request for entity \(entity)")
} But i only got errors

Comment: Yes, you're mixing Objective-C and Swift.  All the code I see in your question is Objective C.  You should be doing something like: `NSError *error = nil; recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:&error]; if(error) { NSLog(@"error from AVAudioRecorder is %@", [error localizedDescription]); }`.  If there's an error, it will print out in the console.

Comment: I did not get any errors in the console. but now the program is wokring fine with each part seperatly. I can get music from itunes libary and stream this, and i can record and play local. It's the connection between the recorded adio and the mulipeer connectivity i dont have. If you understend what I mean?